# Unable to open WebDeploy port (8172) on Azure

Tags: azure, port, firewall, webdeploy, azure-cloud-services

I'm unable to open a webdeploy port (8172) on my Azure machine.

[image]

[image]

I added an endpoint on Azure:
[image]

Added rules to the Firewall:
[image]

Tried even disable the firewall...

No success.

What else can I check?

The problem started from some message about certificate. I am not sure it linked to the problem but I am looking for the problem for two days and have no idea what else I can do...

Thank you.

Comment: Is the port listening for 0.0.0.0:port when you check `netstat -anbo`on the windows machine locally?

Comment: @NancyXiong-MSFT could you please explain what you mean? How can I know?

Comment: Is this the answer to your question? http://prntscr.com/ll038y

Comment: Why does it say 8173 in your screenshot? Shouldn't that be 8172 instead?

Comment: @evilSnobu it is the private port. The public (also on the screenshot) is 8172.

Comment: So you changed the Webdeploy default config to listen on 8173? By default it only listens on 8172.

Comment: @evilSnobu no. On Azure I have public and private ports. As a public I have the common 8172 port, and as a private (it can not be the same as the public) I have set 8173.

Comment: Just set everything to 8172 and you should be good. You are piping through to that VM on a port no one is listening on (817**3**)

Comment: @evilSnobu https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nMUbL8C1dSZTa3y-6fzjzuPFiHG10Gt5/view

Answer (score 1):

When you set up endpoints on a Windows virtual machine by using the classic deployment model. You could change the private port to 8172 for webdeploy. It seems that the **private port** is used by the virtual machine to listen for incoming traffic:

> The public port is used by the Azure load balancer to listen for
>   incoming traffic to the virtual machine from the internet. The private
>   port is used by the virtual machine to listen for incoming traffic,
>   typically destined to an application or service running on the virtual
>   machine.

### Update

After chatting with you, now you are facing the issue that you cannot change the public and private port to the same due to the floating IP address is enabled. I found there is a note that changing floating IP status takes effect until you save it in the UI. You can first create a test rule like public port 8001, a different private port 8000 because of the current floating IP address is really **enabled**, and select the floating IP address is **disabled**, then save it. Now the disabled floating IP address takes effect now. Then you can add the new rule for public and private port 8172. Delete the test rule.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/classic/setup-endpoints

Comment: Changed but still without success. But seems that you are right and I should continue exploring in this direction...

Comment: Can you [telnet](https://www.acronis.com/en-us/articles/telnet/) 8172 with the public IP of Azure VM when you access the VM outside of Azure VM?

Comment: This is the problem, I can't telnet "Could not open connection to the host, on port 8172: Connect failed"

Comment: Can you check the firewall or other restrcition on the local machine?

Comment: What else can be "restriction"?

Comment: May I know that if the Azure VM is in a virtual network or behind a load balancer?

Comment: Could you check the ACL? It should permit the incoming traffic to the public port of the endpoint based on its source IP address. If the virtual machine is in an Azure virtual network, use [network security groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/security-overview) instead.

Comment: ACL? Could you please help me understand how to do it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184013/discussion-between-igor-and-nancy-xiong-msft).

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this is a Microsoft's bug: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fc51b3fa-72c1-4e3c-a942-7da26acecd0d/endpoints-with-same-publicprivate-port-error?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows

Comment: Seem that it's bug, the first time, you can add the same port, then the second time you can not, I have tried it many times. You can regard the floating IP as enabled even it shows the disabled, then you can add another rule with the different port and select the disabled floating IP, save it. And try to add the same port, don't click the floating IP tab, then save it. It works for me.